# How to unit test presenter method based on an Observable returned value?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mvp, reactivex

Having the following real implementation of a function, where `mTallesPreferences.isUserAuthenticated()` returns an `Observable<Boolean>` type value:

```
override fun showInitialScreen() {
    mTallesPreferences.isUserAuthenticated()
            .subscribe { isAuthenticated ->
                if (isAuthenticated) mView?.showMainScreen()
                else mView?.showAccessScreen()
                mView?.closeCurrentScreen()
            }
 }
```

How can I unit test if `mView?.showAccessScreen()` is called when subscriber gets `isAuthenticated = false`?

I have tried the following approach, but unfortunately `NullPointerException` appears on the scene.

```
class LaunchPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var mView: LaunchContract.View

    @Mock
    lateinit var mTallesPreferences: TallesPreferencesApi

    private lateinit var mPresenter: LaunchPresenter

    @Before
    fun setupLaunchPresenter() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        mPresenter = LaunchPresenter(mTallesPreferences)
    }

    @Test
    fun testShowInitialScreenNotAuthenticated() {
        mPresenter.showInitialScreen()
        Mockito.`when`(mTallesPreferences.isUserAuthenticated()).thenReturn(Observable.just(false))
        Mockito.verify(mView).showAccessScreen()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions are in the wrong order. When you call `showInitialScreen()` the `mTallesPreferences.isUserAuthenticated()` is not mocked to return the value you want. Re-order your test method like:

```
@Test
fun testShowInitialScreenNotAuthenticated() {
    Mockito.`when`(mTallesPreferences.isUserAuthenticated()).thenReturn(Observable.just(false))
    mPresenter.showInitialScreen()
    Mockito.verify(mView).showAccessScreen()
}
```